# Can't Undo, Can't Redo in vb6

Tags: vb6

Anyone knows why these tools are disabled?

I'm quite new to this environment.

[image: http://screencast.com/t/5xTkNBCtf2f]

Comment: It might depend on the action you are trying to undo... For instance - I don't believe you can't undo a cut operation on a form.

Comment: @broy22,  `VB.Net` <> `VBA` <> `VB6`, please remove the wrong ones.

Answer (score 1):

Only some actions in VB6 can be undone.

In general, code changes ("typing" it usually calls it) can be undone, while changes to forms - moving, placing controls etc - can't be.

This is somewhat frustrating in my experience, as accidentally moving a control is often more difficult to put right than making some typos in code.

Comment: Forms can be locked as a way to prevent accidentally moving a control. This is very useful when working on code on a form where the design has been finalised.

Comment: Useful - but I tend to get problems along the lines of "I wanted to draw a selection box, but misclicked and draged the control. "Be less clumsy" is probably the solution needed here.